# How to Insert Dynamic Fields to a Document In MongoDB Java Driver

Tags: java, mongodb

```
 {
      "_id" : ObjectId("5888ae5f1495062544ac7951"),
      "site" : "gfhfh",
      "keywords" : {
        "keyword 1" : {
          "dailyranks" : {
            "2017-01-28" : {
              "rank" : 1,
            }
         **Dynamic data should add here by date ** 
          } 
        } 
      }
    }
```

I have tried to insert keyword rank by date. I want to add keyword rank each day. but it doesn't insert only update date and values. I have used following code in java.

```
for (DBObject dbo : result) {
            DBObject keywordlist = (DBObject) dbo.get("keywords");
            BasicDBObject a = new BasicDBObject();
            for (String keyword : keywordlist.keySet()) {
                DBObject rank = getRank();
                BasicDBObject rankdate = new BasicDBObject(date, rank);
                BasicDBObject aa = new BasicDBObject("dailyranks", rankdate);
                a.append(keyword, aa);
            }
            coll.update(dbo, new BasicDBObject("$set", new BasicDBObject("keywords", a)), true, false);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need an embedded array for both `keywords` and `dailyranks`.

```
"keywords": [{
    "keyword 1": {
        "dailyranks": [{
            "2017-01-28": {
                "rank": 1,
            }
        }]
    }
}]
```

After you have this structure, you'll use `$push` operator to insert new `rank` into embedded doc array.

You'll use `$set` if you trying to replace the entire embedded array.